# Source Control Server on Windows With Custom Highlighting Support

Tags: windows, git, version-control, server, syntax-highlighting

We have an old language we use to write scripts on our optimization software at work (Called MoDL if anybody is familiar w/ it). At the moment we're trying to have some kind of source control set up between couple of the engineers that work on this topic. What we want is to have a central repository of common applications. This would help the team maintain and improve these tools in a controlled environment while giving the more senior members of the team to check merges.

We have couple constraints to adhere for company regulations and I couldn't find any tool that fits our requirements yet.

1. We cannot use hosted solutions, anything we do has to be on company's network
2. If there's a web component to the source control server that we can keep markdown documentation, that'd make our life much better. We really don't want to keep documentation in random Excel, Word or text files.
3. We'd very much like custom syntax highlighting support for MoDL. We have a base package we developed to use in Sublime Text and would like to transform it to be used w/ our browser viewers as well
4. It'd be much preferred if this was on a Windows machine. We can do Linux but it would require much more resources (again, because of IT policies of our company)
5. We'd like to use git, but we're also open to other version control systems

If anybody can help us with finding a tool or pointing us in the right direction, that'd be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options if you want to self-host

- You could take a look at [Stash](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bitbucket/server) (from Atlassian). You can integrate Jira (bug/feature tracker), Confluence (a wiki) and a few other things with it too. Seems like [you can install it on Windows](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/STASH013/Installing+Stash+on+Windows) as well. I've used Stash before and while its quite good I prefer GitHub Enterprise. Jira is great however
- If you can relax your Windows only constraint then I'd much rather go with [Github Enterprise](https://enterprise.github.com). Its the same clean UI as GitHub. Their server comes pre-packaged in a Linux VM so all you need to do is run it on VMWare and its very easy to do. Their support is great as well. It is slightly expensive however but definitely worth it. You can also integrate Jira (although their inbuilt issue tracker is quite good too)
- [Bonobo](https://bonobogitserver.com/) is a free and open source server. I've not used it personally but it has a nice functional UI. Definitely worth a try
- [Gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/) is another alternative. I've never used it personally but its fairly popular and not pricey. Again however I don't think they have a windows version but you could run it on Windows as a Linux VM

As far as the syntax highlighting goes however sorry I can't comment on it since I've never used MoDL and it doesn't seem as widely used. But you might be able to add plugins or specify custom highlighting rules to get that working

Comment: I think from set-up and feature perspective, Stash makes the most sense for our use case. They have custom highlight support as well, with [Syntax Highlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/), so all we need to do is convert our TextMate style highlights to that. The price also makes it very competitive.
Funny story, our organization actually uses GitHub Enterprise, but they think it's "insecure" to set up a separate group and give specific access rights to  us.

Comment: Wow that's quite restrictive. Yea I agree Stash licensing is quite cheap specially for small teams. I still prefer GitHub over it but Stash is a solid tool as well